# What are the ways to automatically synchronize custom application events with Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, synchronization

I have an application that manages some user events.
I want to add a service that automatically (in background) synchronize user events with his Google Calendar (both ways).

First, I wonder if it exists some solution (even commercial ones) that provides this kind of service out of the box?
If not, I suppose this is a bunch of work and I immediately see a technical problem: the authentication. The Google Calendar API indicates that you must use an OAuth authentication.
As far as I know OAuth requires user login credentials so how the application could synchronize user event in background (with no user interaction)?

Comment: So you want to synchronize your events to user's Google Cal without their permission? :) You need to implement authentication and then use the credentials to synchronize the calendar.

Comment: Not exactly ;-) I simply cannot understand how I can get user credentials once and use it later in background to synchronize his events. According to the documentation (http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth), each authentication will require user authorization.